# Chrome keyboard losses focus when using two finger scroll

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad, scrolling

I Have a Dell XPS 15 (9530), Chrome 34.0.1847.116.

When using two finger swipe on the touch pad in order to scroll, the tab wouldn't accept keyboard presses anymore, e.g. the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> wouldn't go back, <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> wouldn't open find bar.

There is an [open bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=361942) in the Chromium project, but I am not sure if its related to Chrome or to Windows / drivers (I use latest Synaptic drivers.)

In Internet Explorer, the behavior is usually fine.

Any ideas how to fix ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also like Ofiris, I did not have these records (#2 and #3 in speedplane's post) in my registry. But on blind faith, I added these entries in RegEdit.

Also, step #4 above is not necessarily visible for all users afflicted with this issue, as it wasn't for me. So even after turning stuff visible, I wasn't able to see these controls. Fortunately, from https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361942#c38, htwiz2002@gmail.com was able to document the equivalent of step #4 in the registry, which is

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh]
"GlobalScrollingConfig"=dword:00000009

That did it for me!

Comment: I applied the .reg file in the link, restarted, and all seems to be well now.

Comment: Confirm here that setting `GlobalScrollingConfig`=`9` (it was `1`) fixed my issue. Win 8.1, Dell m3800, Chrome 39. Also, faster way than regedit, from cmd: `reg add HKCU\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh /v GlobalScrollingConfig /t REG_DWORD /d 9 /f`

Answer (score 0):

The link you have is only one step from the answer. On #21 it links to the original bug report, whose #85 gave a solution.
Credit [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=351995) on #85

This works on my machine:

1. Win+R regedit
2. under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl\Controls\2Scrolling\Dialog\1Under pointer`, change `visibility` to 0
3. under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl\Controls\2Scrolling\Dialog\2Selected item`, change `visibility` to 0
4. Control panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Mouse -> Device Settings Tab -> Settings (which opens the Synaptics setting page) -> Select Scrolling -> Click Cog Image to open Scrolling Settings
   **Change 'scroll selected item' to 'scroll item under pointer'**

That's it. Last month I had the problem on both my Linux and Win machine, but now the problem is gone on my Linux system. If you still have the problem on Linux try to update your chrome, or fiddle with `synclient`.

This seems to be a problem with Chrome rather than Synaptics. What's described here is only a workaround, and it might affect scrolling experience in other programs.

Comment: I don't have these records in my registry (Windows 8).

Comment: Do you have your Synaptics driver installed properly?

Comment: Yes, see the other answer.